# why margin top does not work in anchor tag but in button in works?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the button by anchor tag without button tag and I am writing css for that but it's doesn't take margin-top.
My css code is:

```
.btn{
     background: #881f00;
     color: #FFF;
     padding: 5px 12px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     margin-top:20px;
    }
```

Above code define margin top can be work in below html code with button tags:

```
<button class="btn"><a href="#" class="btn">+view more</a></button>
```

But margin top does not work in below html tags:-

```
<a href="#" class="btn">+view more</a>
```

I am really confused how and where this can be happened. I am googling from last 2 hr but I don't get the exact answer so I feel greatfull if anyone can solve this issue. Thank you!!!

Comment: Provide a demo in jsfiddle.net or alike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your a element to be `inline-block`. This will add, among the capabilities of the block level elements, the top margin capability, yet keep it *in line* with the rest of your content:

```css
.btn{
     background: #881f00;
     color: #FFF;
     padding: 5px 12px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     margin-top:20px;
     display: inline-block; /*this is it*/
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn"><a href="#" class="btn">+view more</a></button>
<a href="#" class="btn">+view more</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

`a` is not a block level element. Try to set `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to the `a` tag and it will work.

There are other HTML elements that are set to `display: inline` by default:

[Inline_elements (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements)

Comment: sure, but not the margin-top

Comment: You are correct. My bad. inline-block would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Use **display: inherit** and then give the **margin-top**, it'll work

```
.btn{
 background: #881f00;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 5px 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: inherit;
 margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `display:block` or `overflow:hidden` for the button class.